# php - curl_multi "Illegal characters found in URL"

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I have a php script for a URL status checker tool that will check given URLs and show the ones with 404 error.

StatusCheckerRequest has the input with "\n" seperated URLs

```
public function PostStatusChecker(StatusCheckerRequest $request){
    $urls = $request->source;
    $seperateURLs = explode("\n", $urls);
    // -- create all the individual cURL handles and set their options
    $curl_handles = array();
    foreach ($seperateURLs as $url) {
        $curl_handles[$url] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$url], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$url], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$url], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$url], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    }
    // -- start going through the cURL handles and running them
    $curl_multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
    $i = 0; // count where we are in the list so we can break up the runs into smaller blocks
    $block = array(); // to accumulate the curl_handles for each group we'll run simultaneously
    $results = array();
    $curlErrors = array();
    foreach ($curl_handles as $a_curl_handle) {
        $i++; // increment the position-counter

        // add the handle to the curl_multi_handle and to our tracking "block"
        curl_multi_add_handle($curl_multi_handle, $a_curl_handle);
        $block[] = $a_curl_handle;

        // -- check to see if we've got a "full block" to run or if we're at the end of out list of handles
        if (($i % BLOCK_SIZE == 0) or ($i == count($curl_handles))) {
            // -- run the block
            $running = NULL;
            do {
                // track the previous loop's number of handles still running so we can tell if it changes
                $running_before = $running;

                // run the block or check on the running block and get the number of sites still running in $running
                curl_multi_exec($curl_multi_handle, $running);
                print_r (curl_multi_info_read($curl_multi_handle));
            } while ($running > 0);


            // -- once the number still running is 0, curl_multi_ is done, so check the results
            foreach ($block as $handle) {
                // HTTP response code
                $code = curl_getinfo($handle,  CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                $results['httpCode'][] = $code;

                // cURL error number
                 $curl_errno = curl_errno($handle);
                $results['curlErrorNo'][] = $curl_errno;

                // cURL error message
                $curl_error = curl_error($handle);
                $results['curlErrorMessage'][] = $curl_error;        

                // remove the (used) handle from the curl_multi_handle
                curl_multi_remove_handle($curl_multi_handle, $handle);
            }

            // reset the block to empty, since we've run its curl_handles
            $block = array();
        }
    }
    // close the curl_multi_handle once we're done
    curl_multi_close($curl_multi_handle);
    print_r($results);
    die();
}
```

I used an example of curl_multi_exec from Stack Overflow,and when I check the results with these URLs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stackoverfloww.com
    [1] => www.laravel2.com
    [2] => http://stackoverflow.com
    [3] => http://laravel.com
)
```

The output is

```
[httpCode] => Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 301
)

[curlErrorMessage] => Array
(
    [0] => Illegal characters found in URL
    [1] => Illegal characters found in URL
    [2] => Illegal characters found in URL
    [3] => 
)
```

I tried with different inputs and the results are always the last URL returns 200 or 301,and the others are all 0.I also check the results of curl_multi_info_read and the results are all 3 for the "illegal character found" urls,and the last one's value is 0.

Can you please help what is wrong with this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search of the cURL source code reveals that this error comes from the fact that the URL being supplied to `CURLOPT_URL` contains the characters `\r` and/or `\n`.

From `lib/url.c`:

```
  /* We might pass the entire URL into the request so we need to make sure
   * there are no bad characters in there.*/
  if(strpbrk(data->change.url, "\r\n")) {
    failf(data, "Illegal characters found in URL");
    return CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT;
  }
```

You should run the URL through `$url = trim($url);` since there is probably a remaining `\r` or `\n` on the end of the URL.